# PeopleSoft make page readonly - specific rows

Tags: peoplesoft, rowset

I have a page that contains a parent record and several children records.  There is a field (level 1) that is a checkbox that is a "final draft" field - after this is checked no more changes can be made (even in correction mode); a new row/effdt must be inserted.  The children records are all in level 2.  Right now, what I have is:

```
&RS7 = GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL);
&final_draft = &RS7.GetRow(1).getrecord(Record.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL).getfield     (Field.FINAL_VALUE).Value;

If &final_draft = "Y" Then
  Page.AVZ_JD_DTL_PG.DisplayOnly = True;
 Else
  Page.AVZ_JD_DTL_PG.DisplayOnly = False;
 End-If;
```

So let's say i'm in correction mode, and I have 3 rows - effdts 1/1/2012, 5/1/2012, and 6/1/2012, with the checkbox checked for the row dated 5/1/2012, as I am "paging"/"scrolling' throught the effective dates, I want the row dated 1/1/2012 to be editable, the row dated 5/1/2012 read-only and then the row dated 6/1/2012 to be editable.

I think maybe I will need to "disable" each rowset individually, rather than the page as a whole.  I'm just getting my head around rowsets/scrolls, and earlier in the program I am doing some manipulation:

&RS1 = GetLevel0().GetRow(1).GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL).GetRow(1).GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_RESP_TBL);
   &RS2 = GetLevel0().GetRow(1).GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL).GetRow(1).GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_EXPR_TBL);

&RS1.Sort(AVZ_JD_RESP_TBL.ORDER_SEQ, "A");
   &RS2.Sort(AVZ_JD_EXPR_TBL.ORDER_SEQ, "A");

The question is, how do I know which row that I am currently viewing, then grab the FINAL_VALUE field for that row, and then, grey/disable everything on the page for that effdt? (then of course, if you go past that effdt to one that does not have that checkbox ticked, everything will need to be editable again).

Thanks

Comment: An alternate option that my user just agreed to:  Make all historical rows read-only, and if the current row has the checkbox ticked, make it read-only.  They do need to be able to change the current row, so I know they'll need correction mode -- is there a way I can make historical rows read-only, leaving the current row editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the level 1 scolls looking for the checkbox, then if found loop through the level 2 scrolls and then set the **Active** attribute for the row to false.

I don't have a PeopleSoft system available to test this code, but it would be something like this:

```
&LEVEL0 = your level 0 record
&LEVEL1 = &LEVEL0.GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL); /* handle to level 1 */
For &I = 1 To &LEVEL1.ActiveRowCount
    if &LEVEL1(&I).final_draft = "Y" then   /* check box is on */
        &LEVEL2 = &LEVEL0(1).&LEVEL1(&I).GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_EXPR_TBL);
        For &J = 1 to &LEVEL2.ActiveRowCount
            &LEVEL0(1).&LEVEL1(&I).&LEVEL2(&J).AVZ_JD_EXPR_TBL.Active = "False";
        End-For;
    End-If;
End-For;
```

Assuming your level 1 record is **AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL** and your level 2 is **AVZ_JD_EXPR_TBL**. Please double-check PeopleBooks for the exact syntax but I think that is correct.